# vbNewLine, VbCrLf and Char(13) are not working in custom Function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to create a function that will split its own content into multiple lines. I need to create a custom one because I will be doing more operations on it so **I can't use built-in functions** like `CONCATENATE` or `TEXTJOIN`.

My code:

```vb
Public Function Description(formula As String) As String
    arr = Split(formula, ";")
    For Each Item In arr
        arr2 = Split(Item, ":")
        Description = Description & "Row " & arr2(0) & " Item " & arr2(1) & vbNewLine
    Next
```

I use it in a cell with `=Description(string)` where `string` is an one-line text like:

> 2:1;3:2;4:5

It **should** return:

```
Row 2 Item 1
Row 3 Item 2
Row 4 Item 5
```

**Instead** it returns:

```
Row 2 Item 1Row 3 Item 2Row 4 Item 5
```

I tried to use `vbNewLine`, `vbCrLf`, `vbCr`, `vbLf`, `Char(10)` and `Char(13)`, nothing works.
Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: define 'it returns' - is this how it shows in the sheet? what shows if you `debug.print Description` after the loop?

Comment: Please add your original string (formula) as example input. in your question

Comment: Code works for me. You need to add a word wrap to the cell format of the cell where you output the result

Comment: Excel uses `vbLf` as the new line character in a cell. In order to see it working, resize the cell and enable word wrap in its format.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes this is how it shows in the cell, I added a screenshot. Debug.print returns the correct string (with multiple lines). Function in the cell returns the wrong one (in one line).

Comment: `vbLf` is the way to go (its length is 1). Also, after the loop use `Description = Left(Description, Len(Description) - 1)` to get rid of the last `vbLf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `vbLf`-character (seems that `vbNewline` also works) to get a line break in Excel.
However, you need to set the `WrapText` property in the cell, else the text will be displayed as one single line.

```
ActiveCell = "ABC" & vbLf & "XYZ"
ActiveCell.WrapText = True
```

Comment: Wrap text worked. It's strange because last time I tested this solution it didn't wrap my text properly. Now it works how it should. I had to use vbLf or vbNewLine and turn on Wrap Text on the column with function.